# Selecting Face selects entire object!

Tags: edit-mode

Hi everyone i am a novice to blender and have been watching [tutorial by Chic Areon on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xj04Pj_Jk7s)

I am doing just as she says by choosing select face in edit mode but when i click on my cube it still hightlights the whole thing. I have even tried pressing <kbd>P</kbd>  but that doesn't look right either.

Can anyone give me some pointers on what to do from here.

Comment: have you got everything deselected before you click on the face?

Answer (score 0):

make sure everything is deselected (alt + a) in edit mode. Press the number 3 for face selection and make sure you have the selection tool enabled. Click on the centre of the face.